# Pseudo class does not work when using shouldForwardProp / how use several filters in shouldForwardProp in styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

1 - When I use pseudo selectors in `styled-components` after using `withConfig` stuff somehow the applied pseudo-selectors do not work.

```
const Input = styled.input.attrs(({
  type: "number",
  size: 2,
  placeholder: "Your number",
}))`
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  :disabled {
          border: red 20px solid;
      }
  ${({foo, borderWidth}) =>
    foo &&
    css`
      color: purple;
      padding: 0.3rem;
      outline: none;
      border-width: ${borderWidth};
      ::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
      ::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
      }
      ::placeholder {
        color: purple;
      }
      &:focus {
        border-color: red;
        padding: 0.3rem;
      }
    `}
`;


const Div = styled.div.withConfig({
  shouldForwardProp: (prop, defaultValidatorFn) =>
    !["foo"].includes(prop) && defaultValidatorFn(prop),
})`
  :disabled {
      border: gray 200px solid;
  };
  ${({ foo }) => `
 background-color: ${foo}
 `}
`;
```

on `Input` everything works well. On the other hand, on `Div` `:disabled` does not work when called in the rendered `jsx` element.

Comment: I found your way of creating components overcomplicated. I have like 4 years of exp in React and styled-components, created multiple enterprise projects and I have never had to use `withConfig`, `attrs` and so on. Consider to not complicate your life, you can easily set the `type`, `size` and other props directly in JSX.

Comment: thanks @kinduser. This example of mine is not a real life one. I spent yesterday reading through the documentation of styled-components so I can use it for the next project and this question of mine is purely theoretical. I honestly agree that on a real life project things must be written clear and as simple as possible. I have made two questions here on stack overflow after reading the whole docs just to understand little bit better the library on these little theoretical things.

Comment: Unfortunately tried these functions just a few times, I dont feel like I have enough knowledge to lecture others.